# OpenCL can't set kernel args for constant array

Tags: c, opencl, nvidia

I am trying to set the arguments of my kernel and I keep getting CL_INVALID_ARG_SIZE when I try to set arg-0 which is the bounds. The strange thing is if I just comment out the first clSetKernelArgs all the others seem to work.  I would think it might be an issue with the constant array except that it works for rand_seeds.

```
success = clSetKernelArg(solver_kernel, 0, sizeof(cl_float) * 10, bounds);
    if(success != CL_SUCCESS)
    {
        printf("%d\n", success);
        exit(1);
    }
    success = clSetKernelArg(solver_kernel, 1, sizeof(cl_float) * 2, seeds);
    if(success != CL_SUCCESS)
    {
        printf("%d\n", success);
        exit(1);
    }
    success = clSetKernelArg(solver_kernel, 2, sizeof(cl_int), &trials);
    if(success != CL_SUCCESS)
    {
        printf("%d\n", success);
        exit(1);
    }
    success = clSetKernelArg(solver_kernel, 3, sizeof(cl_int), &start_temp);
    if(success != CL_SUCCESS)
    {
        printf("%d\n", success);
        exit(1);
    }
```

Here is the header of my kernel

```
  __kernel void solver_kernel
    (
        __constant float bounds[10],
        __constant int rand_seeds[2],
        int trials,
        int start_temp
    )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [OpenCL specification](https://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/sdk/1.2/docs/man/xhtml/clSetKernelArg.html):

> The memory object specified as argument value must be a buffer object
>   (or NULL) if the argument is declared to be a pointer of a built-in or
>   user defined type with the `__global` or `__constant` qualifier.

So you have to create a buffer first and set that as your kernel argument. Should look like this

```
cl_mem bounds_buffer = clCreateBuffer(context, CL_MEM_READ_ONLY | CL_MEM_COPY_HOST_PTR, sizeof(cl_float) * 10, bounds, &success); 
success = clSetKernelArg(solver_kernel, 0, sizeof(cl_mem), bounds_buffer);
```

You need to do the same for the `rand_seeds` argument, even if you do not get an error at this line (maybe because `sizeof(cl_float) * 2 == sizeof(cl_mem)` by chance, which will still yield incorrect results).

Comment: So when I say CL_MEM_READ_ONLY does that go to the constant memory.  Because I know I have a lot less constant memory than global memory.  Why I ask this is I might want to create a large buffer (in global meory) which I will only read from using CL_MEM_READ_ONLY.

Comment: The actual limitation of the buffer size for __constant arguments is specified on the page I linked to above. You can allocate larger buffers with the CL_MEM_READ_ONLY flag but you cannot use them as the value to an argument that is declared __constant.

Comment: Ok thanks.  I am a CUDA programmer and I am just used to declaring constants and directly using cudaMemcpyToSymbol to initialize them.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use the buffer + `__constant` way if your buffer does never change. Here is an alternative.

There are actually 2 ways of using constant memory in a kernel:

- Using a standard buffer + `__constant` flag
- Using a struct argument

The first one is preferred (**so please use the accepted answer by @Jan**), since you explicitly say how you prefer your data to be handled. But in practice all the implementations also use constant memory for the second case. Since the data that it is passed to the kernel is static and not modifiable anyway.

So, you could rewrite your kernel like:

```
 typedef struct float_10 { float f[10];} float_10;
 typedef struct int_2 { int i[2];}int_2;

  __kernel void solver_kernel
    (
        float_10 bounds,
        int_2 rand_seeds,
        int trials,
        int start_temp
    )
```

Should have same performance.

EDITED: Since you need structs, not arrays

Comment: So in normal C even if I give array bounds to a function argument it is still treated as a pointer so I take it this is different in opencl c?

Comment: Now you are making me doubt.... I don't really remember if when I used it I passed a structure of N floats, or an array of N floats. Both values have the same size, however they are threated differently. Maybe this answer is invalid.

Comment: I think you would need to wrap it in a struct.

Comment: Edited sicne I am not sure of the other approach. Thoug should be a way to hack it.